# Trouble installing pip on Mac running 10.6

Tags: python, pip

1 I installed python using brew.

2 Python `get-pip.py` results the following:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

3 When I am trying to use pip to install other things I am getting this:

```
pip install nose
-bash: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Content: bad interpreter: No such file or directory.
```

Comment: what happens if you run `python -m pip install nose`? if you get the same error what about `python -m tkinter`?  The error message would suggest your `Python.app` is broken or not in the correct spot which seems very odd...

Comment: python -m pip --version gives: pip 9.0.1 from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)

Comment: sorry for changing my comment on you, if you get an output from `--version` that'd be useful for me too.

Comment: running pip --version gives: -bash: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Content: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: ok so it's just the `pip` command (shortcut) that's broken, you can use `python -m pip` instead of `pip` to do your stuff: `python -m pip install nose` but I'd like to debug the error you are getting

Comment: Thanks Tadhg, it is working with python -m pip install nose

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using python that came with your System (under `/System/Library/...`) where normally python would be `/Library/...` the pip command is looking for the python interpreter in the wrong place.

If you are using the python that came with your Operating system it may be outdated so I'd recommend installing it from [python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/), it will install to the place pip is expecting so it'd solve your current issue as well.

If you are happy with the version of python you have installed and the `python` command works correctly and pip is installed as a module then you can use `python -m pip` to run pip commands.  No changes necessary!

---

### If you really want to use the `pip` shortcut with a non-standard install.

*(I personally don't recommend this as the other options are better but may be useful for someone at some point)*

The error you got is specifically because the shebang in the pip file is incorrect, so you can go fix it if needed.

first locate the `pip` command and the `python` command with `which pip` and `which python`, the python one is machine code but you can read `pip` in a text editor, this is what mine looks like:

```
#!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from pip import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

The first like starting with `#!` is the shebang, it indicates the path of the python executable that can run this file (the path from `which python`) so just change it to the path of the python executable and save and you should be good to go!

Answer (score 0):

Short advice: Use [Pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv).

The native installation of Python on macs is a bit tweaked and it's also used by several components of the operating system, so it's better not to tinker with it if possible.

Using Pyenv you can set several virtual Python environments which can have specific Python versions and be automatically enabled for a specific folder.

For example, suppose you want to use Python 3.6 for your project. First you have to install Pyenv and its virtual environment module:

`brew install pyenv pyenv-virtualenv
pyenv install 3.6.0`

Then you can create your own environment based on Python 3.6:

`pyenv virtualenv 3.6.0 my-own-py36`

Once it finishes, you should be in your own environment, and `pip` will work for that specific version.

Anyway, maybe the most comfortable option is to have it automatically enabled for a specific folder. You can do that going to your project root and typing:

`pyenv local my-own-py36`

I hope you find this helpful, you can check the Pyenv documentation if you have any doubts.